# passing a function as a prop from a functional component to a class component

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react by coding a gamertag generator. It generates random tags and keeps a list, and each can be rated. My main app is a functional component  utilizing the useState hook to set state: an array of objects with details about the tags, namely a star rating system.

I generate each gamertag using a react component Tag, within, it uses a functional component, RenderStars to draw the stars. Each tag stars off with 0 stars, so 5 empty stars, and I want the user to change rating by clicking on however many stars, 1-5. RenderStars will then draw however many empty and filled stars as needed.

I have a function in App, changeStars, that I can't seem to get any of the child components to call successfully. I am passing the function to the child components through props.

I've tried writing changeStars in arrow notation and as a plain function. I've tried it without requiring any parameters. I've tried calling it within Tag just using a button. There's other ways I've messed with it that I can't quite recall, just messing with the syntax and trying other things from stackexchange and articles.

I don't bind the function because it's created in a functional component.

This seems like a super basic task and I can't figure it out. **Yes i've read the Docs from react.js**

Here is some of the code, I'll try to take out as much as possible:

```
function App() {
  const [tagInventory, setTagInventory] = useState([]);
  const latestTag = tagInventory[tagInventory.length - 1] ? tagInventory[tagInventory.length -1] : null;

  const handleAdd = (tag) => {
    uses hook to add tag to state
  }

  const makeTag = () => {
    creates random tag
  }

  function changeStars(stars,key) {
    console.log(stars, key);
    //this will change the star rating of an individual tag
  }

return (
    <main>
         A bunch of amazing interface html
           <section className="tagInventory">
            {tagInventory.map( (item) =>
              <Tag
                key={item.timeStamp}
                tagItem={item}
              />
              ) }
          </section>
     </main>
  );
};

class Tag extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const item = this.props.tagItem;
    const stars = this.props.tagItem.stars;
    const key = this.props.tagItem.timeStamp;
    const tagClass = this.props.newTag ? "tag-item new-item" : "tag-item";
    
    return (
      <div className={tagClass}>
          code to generate cool tag info
        </div>
          <RenderStars
            stars={stars}
            changeStars={changeStars}
            newTag={false}
            key={key}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const RenderStars = (props) => {
  // ref for using symbol tag https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/
  return (
       i load svg of stars then can display as many as i need later...    
      
       now i draw 4 stars, for the example i'll stop at the first, here's the call..
        {props.stars === 0 &&
        <div>
          <svg className="empty-star" onClick={() => props.changeStars(4,props.key)}>
          <use xlinkHref="#empty-star" />
          
          now the other stars and whatnot

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: *How exactly* did you try to pass `changeStars` to a child component?

Comment: *"I am passing the function [`changeStars`] to the child components through props."* - No, you are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to pass the function `changeStars` from App to Tag and then to RenderStars, is that correct?

If so, you're forgetting to pass it from App to Tag

App:

```
   <section className="tagInventory">
    {tagInventory.map( (item) =>
      <Tag
        key={item.timeStamp}
        tagItem={item}
      />
      ) }
  </section>
```

Should be passing the function:

```
           <section className="tagInventory">
            {tagInventory.map( (item) =>
              <Tag
                key={item.timeStamp}
                tagItem={item}
                changeStars={changeStars}
              />
              ) }
          </section>
```

And then on Tag:

```
const changeStars = this.props.changeStars;
```

Comment: ahh, i missed that, i call Tag twice, and was passing changeStars the first time but not the second. THANKS!